# How to check YouTtube videos URL is validation now?

Tags: php, regex, youtube, vimeo

I have some code that check YouTube videos URL is valid in PHP.

```
<?php
      $rx = '~
      ^(?:https?://)?              # Optional protocol
       (?:www\.)?                  # Optional subdomain
       (?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)  # Mandatory domain name
       /watch\?v=([^&]+)           # URI with video id as capture group 1
       ~x';

      $has_match = preg_match($rx, $vid1, $matches);
?>
```

it works similarly for this kind of URLs e.g.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpPG0bKHYKc

But it doesn't work correctly for some URLs such as:

https://youtu.be/auz2t9nBcwU

Comment: I'm gonna get correctly information and add video urls in my blogs.

Comment: As you know, https://youtu.be/auz2t9nBcwU is also valid video url in youtub but my module doesn't detect this is correction url.

Comment: $vid1 is video's url.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpPG0bKHYKc

Comment: Thanks, but second url is also valid, I think.
Let you try it.

Comment: You can get this url in Youtube video control > menu(right mouse click ) > copy url.

Comment: Thanks your advice.
But I don't understand.
Can you provide me more details code?

Comment: Posted an answer which I think explains what I mean... if not post a comment. If it explains and works please accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments in your regex state the protocol and subdomain are optional. Either form of the domain name is allowed. The last part of the regex is where you run into issues. The `/watch\?v=` then anything but an `&` is required. Your second URL doesn't have `/watch` in it. You could make the `/watch` optional but then `youtube.com/anything` would be allowed. I'd recommend putting the allowed formats in your alteration. Something like:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/watch\?v=([^&\n]+)|youtu\.be/([a-zA-Z\d]+))$
```

I think would do it for you.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TKPtPD/1

The `[a-zA-Z\d]+` is also what appears to be the valid characters after the `youtu.be` domain. If more characters can be present you'll need to update that class.

Comment: It's really helpful for me.
Thanks a lot.